# Literal dot confusion, copy all hidden files

Tags: clipboard, regex

It works fine when I copy all hidden files using regex:

```
cp -r source/\.[^.]* destination/
```

and it just copies exactly files beggining with a dot `.` .

However, I found the following works also:

```
cp -r source/.[^.]* destination/
```

In regular expression, doesn't dot `.` mean "any singular character"? So why does not the second command copy regular files (those not hidden) ? 
Why is the dot `.` interpreted literally in `cp` command?

Comment: But the bash shell doesn't use regular expressions, it uses its own expansion rules.

Comment: With Zsh you don't get ".." and "." when you do ".*" :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`cp`, as well as the rest of the built-in shell commands, accept and expand **glob patters** and not regular expressions. They are similar in some aspects, different in many. For example, the `.` is literal in globs, and *any single character* is matched with `?`.

Your friend in this case is `man 7 glob`.

Answer (score 1):

Bash doesn't use regular expressions at all, it uses its own rules for wildcard expansion (called "globbing".  The dot is simply a character, and the '^' character negates whatever follows.  so the first example matches files starting with a dot, not followed by a second dot, and the next one does the same; There is no need to escape the dot but it is accepted anyway.

Edit:  After looking at the suggested "man 7 glob" by Marios, I was mistaken, I think, about the '^' character.  It seems to say that `[^.]` would be undefined rather than a not character.  Bash uses an exclamation point for negation.

Comment: Oh, I really didn't know much about globbing, your comment cautioned me of the great difference between glob and regex. It seems that I need a lot of reading-manual work, thank you.